# Change a variable using constructor with php

Tags: php, html, constructor

Why does the constructor not change the name of the variable? It tells me $name is not defined.

```
<?php
class Person{
public $name;
  public function __construct($var){
  $this->name = $var;
  }
  public function greet(){
  echo "Hello, my name is ".$name.", nice to meet you :-)";
  }
}
$me = new Person("Bob");
$me->greet();
?>
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Stephen,

Comment: `$this->name` !== `$name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use `$this` when access accessing class members in side of your methods, just like you did inside of your constructor:

```
echo "Hello, my name is ".$this->name.", nice to meet you :-)";
```

Comment: Amazing, just posted this and i got a reply within 30 minutes. I agree with @Andrew, you deserve an upvote!